# ajax $.post not working in bootstrap framework application using leaflet 1.20

Tags: leaflet, jquery

I have a web application using Bootstrap and leaflet.  My jquery ajax call does not work.

```
<!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin="">
</script>

var service_ajax_script="admin_insert_new_incident_ajax_post.php";
 $.post(service_ajax_script,data, processResponse_insert_new_incident).error(errorResponse_insert_new_incident);
```

I get a javascript error on the `$.post` call

> Unable to get property 'lat' of undefined or null reference